# implement butterworth filter in objective c

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, imagefilter

Has anyone implemented the Butterworth filter in objective c? I need to implement this filter [b,a]=butter(n,Wn,'ftype');

Any advice or where I should look for more info?

Thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one written in C, see [previous Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664877/i-need-to-implement-a-butterworth-filter-in-c-is-it-easier-get-a-library-with-th) and [here](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/filters004.txt) for possibilities.